# Android ANR in process: com.android.inputmethod.latin Exception

Tags: android

I have got this type of memory exception some times on my apps, any body  have idea about why this exception is occurred ?

```
E/ActivityThread(  390): Failed to find provider info for com.google.settings
E/ActivityThread(  390): Failed to find provider info for com.google.settings
I/ActivityThread(  390): Publishing provider com.android.globalsearch.SuggestionProvider: com.android.globalsearch.SuggestionProvider
W/ActivityManager(   51): Timeout executing service: ServiceRecord{439b4c30 com.android.inputmethod.latin/.LatinIME}
I/ActivityManager(   51): ANR in process: com.android.inputmethod.latin
I/ActivityManager(   51): Annotation: Executing service ComponentInfo{com.android.inputmethod.latin/com.android.inputmethod.latin.LatinIME}
I/ActivityManager(   51): CPU usage:
I/ActivityManager(   51): Load: 2.07 / 0.89 / 0.35
I/ActivityManager(   51): CPU usage from 27357ms to 1782ms ago:
I/ActivityManager(   51):   system_server: 10% = 3% user + 6% kernel / faults: 8566 minor 447 major
I/ActivityManager(   51):   com.babbleville: 6% = 1% user + 4% kernel / faults: 3031 minor 188 major
I/ActivityManager(   51):   com.android.inputmethod.latin: 5% = 0% user + 4% kernel / faults: 6296 minor 473 major
I/ActivityManager(   51):   com.android.phone: 2% = 0% user + 2% kernel / faults: 3052 minor 101 major
I/ActivityManager(   51):   adbd: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
I/ActivityManager(   51):   logcat: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 291 minor 6 major
I/ActivityManager(   51):   zygote: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 70 minor 3 major
I/ActivityManager(   51):   pdflush: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
I/ActivityManager(   51):   servicemanager: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 16 minor 4 major
I/ActivityManager(   51):   logcat: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 290 minor 7 major
I/ActivityManager(   51):   qemud: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 272 minor 3 major
I/ActivityManager(   51):  +android.process.acore: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
I/ActivityManager(   51): TOTAL: 100% = 9% user + 30% kernel + 59% iowait + 0% irq + 0% softirq
I/ActivityManager(   51): Removing old ANR trace file from /data/anr/traces.txt
I/Process (   51): Sending signal. PID: 384 SIG: 3
I/dalvikvm(  384): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
I/Process (   51): Sending signal. PID: 51 SIG: 3
I/dalvikvm(   51): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
I/dalvikvm(  384): Wrote stack trace to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
I/ActivityThread(  390): Publishing provider com.android.globalsearch.stats: com.android.globalsearch.StatsProvider
I/ActivityThread(  390): Publishing provider contacts;call_log: com.android.providers.contacts.ContactsProvider
I/dalvikvm(   51): Wrote stack trace to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
I/Process (   51): Sending signal. PID: 390 SIG: 3
I/dalvikvm(  390): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
I/Process (   51): Sending signal. PID: 358 SIG: 3
I/dalvikvm(  358): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
I/dalvikvm(  390): Wrote stack trace to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
I/dalvikvm(  358): Wrote stack trace to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
I/Process (   51): Sending signal. PID: 92 SIG: 3
I/dalvikvm(   92): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
I/dalvikvm(   92): Wrote stack trace to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
```

Answer (score 0):

==> ANR in process: com.android.inputmethod.latin
latin ime maybe blocked, find "message history" in your log or get /data/anr/traces.txt to know which process/thread is busy?
And from:
TOTAL: 100% = 9% user + 30% kernel + 59% iowait + 0% irq + 0% softirq

iowait is hight: maybe file read/write in busy status